# Regex Extraction in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a text file that has some data like this :-

```
1/4 cup chopped green onion
1/2 teaspoon salt
1 Tbsp cream
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
```

I want to write a regexp such that my data is divided into groups of 3 like below:-

```
'1/4' 'çup' 'chopped green onion'
'1/2' 'teaspoon' salt'
'1' 'Tbsp' 'cream'
'1' 'teaspoon' 'vanilla extract'
```

It means that my regex should have:

- the first group before the first space,
- second group between the first and second space and
- third group after the second space till the end of line.

What is a possible way to do that?

Comment: Please paste the code you have tried so far

Comment: I know you are asking for Scala, and a regex. You could achieve by using split method and split each line by space. It will be converted to array, and then from that string array you could have 1/4 and cup in the 0th and 1th position. Rest strings you can again merge to form a string. just suggesting a workaround.

Comment: Show the regex you tried and why it didn't work. If you didn't attempt it yet, check the regex documentation.

Comment: to get started here is sample regex that will match line breaks https://regex101.com/r/pF9cV2/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> val RecipeItem = """(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)""".r
RecipeItem: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)

scala> val RecipeItem(qty, unit, ingredient) = "1/4 cup chopped green onion"
qty: String = 1/4
unit: String = cup
ingredient: String = chopped green onion
```