# Parsing ASCII communication with Hardware using Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, parsing, hardware-interface

I am writing software that will interface external device via exchange of ASCII commands. Example:

```
POS? 1 2
=>1=-1158.4405
=>2=+0000.0000
```

where above we ask for position of motorised microscope stage for the 1-st and 2-nd axes. It responds with positions in um. More [details and examples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12073958/E-725_User_PZ197E100_command_subset.pdf).

My Question: is there a library that would ease parsing such string outputs, and/or would help generate queries? 
Otherwise, what are the best practises for parsing and communicating with hardware using Java/Scala?

Comment: You can use the built in String handling and pattern matching library in the JDK.  Best practice would be to use the driver or method the hardware vendor recommends.

Comment: Take a look at [Combinator Parsing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html)

Comment: Built-in Scala string matching will probably suffice. Regular expressions can be helpful. In your example, what is the input and what the output? What strings do you want to generate and parse? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions.  See, for example, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907921/regex-extraction-in-scala/30908393#30908393

Comment: @Madoc, i am sending string "POS? 1 2" and receiving two lines back: "1=-1158.4405" and "2=+0000.0000". These strings have general rules of formatting, see doc in the link above, that would be nice to capture with universal parsing script/library.

Comment: @Karolis Thanks for the clarification. Please understand that I won't browse through a 91-page document to answer the question. SO questions should be self-contained and not depend on external documents. Please ask more concrete questions, in the style of: "Given X, how can I extract Y? This is what I tried: ... And this is why my attempt is not sufficient: ...". This way, your question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to cope with following syntax (see `12.1 Format`):

```
 Reply syntax:
     [<argument>[{SP<argument>}]"="]<value>LF
 Multi-line reply syntax:
     {[<argument>[{SP<argument>}]"="]<value>SP LF}
     [<argument>[{SP<argument>}]"="]<value>LF for the last line!
```

This is my code:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

case class Result(argument: String, value: Float)

class ReplyParser extends RegexParsers{
    override def skipWhitespace = false
    private def floatingPointNumber: Parser[String] = 
        """(-|\+)?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)""".r
    private def value: Parser[Float] = floatingPointNumber ^^ (_.toFloat)
    private def argument: Parser[String] = "[^= \n]+".r
    private def arguments: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(argument," ") <~ "="
    private def result: Parser[List[Result]] = arguments.? ~ value ^^ {
        case arguments ~ value => 
            arguments.getOrElse(List("")).map {
                Result(_,value)
            }
    }
    def reply: Parser[List[Result]] = rep1sep(result, " \n".r) <~ " " ^^ {
        case result => result.flatten
    }
}

object Parsing extends ReplyParser {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val result = parseAll(reply,"a=+000.123 \nc d=-999.567 \n789 ")
        println(s"$result")
    }
}
```